# Find Y given X in Regression (lm) in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict

I have the following regression:

UE_S<-lm(Sus$S~Sus$UE)

I need to find an estimate of Sus$S given Sus$UE is 5.5.

How do I do this? Do I use the predict function? And if so, how?

I have tried various ways of using the predict function but all seem to imply creating new data.frames of new values. I just need to estimate the ONE value of 5.5 for Sus$UE.

Thank you!

Comment: If your data is in a data frame, you should avoid the `$` notation in formulas. If you do `UE_S <- lm(S ~ UE, data = Sus)` Then you would get your result with `predict(UE_S, newdata = data.frame(UE = 5.5))`

Answer (score 1):

Given that your regression is named `model`, you could just do this:

```
c(1, 5.5) %*% model$coefficients
```

This will calculate a matrix calculation between the vector of independent variables (1 for the intercept, 5.5 for `UE`) and the fitted coefficients of your regression. The result will be a scalar.